# Auto play is not working in the lightning carousel

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, salesforce-id

I got this code from http://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/carousel/#About-Carousel. it was supposed to do the auto play function but it is not working, even the round buttons are also not working. am i missing something? i also know about the LWC carousel, but i need to customize some of the things which was not possible on that, so was trying this one.

**code**

```
<template>
<div class="slds-carousel">
<div class="slds-carousel__stage">
<span class="slds-carousel__autoplay">
<button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-border-filled slds-button_icon-x-small" aria-pressed="true" title="Stop auto-play">
<svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
<use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#pause"></use>
</svg>
<span class="slds-assistive-text">Stop auto-play</span>
</button>
</span>
<div class="slds-carousel__panels" style="transform:translateX(-0%)">
<div id="content-id-01" class="slds-carousel__panel" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false" aria-labelledby="indicator-id-01">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-carousel__panel-action slds-text-link_reset" tabindex="0">
<div class="slds-carousel__image">
<img src="/assets/images/carousel/carousel-01.jpg" alt="Visit App Exchange" />
</div>
<div class="slds-carousel__content">
<h2 class="slds-carousel__content-title">Visit App Exchange</h2>
<p>Extend Salesforce with the #1 business marketplace.</p>
</div>
</a>
</div>
<div id="content-id-02" class="slds-carousel__panel" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="indicator-id-02">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-carousel__panel-action slds-text-link_reset" tabindex="-1">
<div class="slds-carousel__image">
<img src="/assets/images/carousel/carousel-02.jpg" alt="Click to Customize" />
</div>
<div class="slds-carousel__content">
<h2 class="slds-carousel__content-title">Click to Customize</h2>
<p>Use the Object Manager to add fields, build layouts, and more.</p>
</div>
</a>
</div>
<div id="content-id-03" class="slds-carousel__panel" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="indicator-id-03">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-carousel__panel-action slds-text-link_reset" tabindex="-1">
<div class="slds-carousel__image">
<img src="/assets/images/carousel/carousel-03.jpg" alt="Download SalesforceA" />
</div>
<div class="slds-carousel__content">
<h2 class="slds-carousel__content-title">Download SalesforceA</h2>
<p>Get the mobile app that&#x27;s just for Salesforce admins.</p>
</div>
</a>
</div>
</div>
<ul class="slds-carousel__indicators" role="tablist">
<li class="slds-carousel__indicator" role="presentation">
<a id="indicator-id-01" class="slds-carousel__indicator-action slds-is-active" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="content-id-01" title="Visit App Exchange tab">
<span class="slds-assistive-text">Visit App Exchange tab</span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="slds-carousel__indicator" role="presentation">
<a id="indicator-id-02" class="slds-carousel__indicator-action" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="content-id-02" title="Click to Customize tab">
<span class="slds-assistive-text">Click to Customize tab</span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="slds-carousel__indicator" role="presentation">
<a id="indicator-id-03" class="slds-carousel__indicator-action" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="content-id-03" title="Download SalesforceA tab">
<span class="slds-assistive-text">Download SalesforceA tab</span>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lightning-carousel`, which allows same behavior. Documentation can be seen here - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-carousel/example

Code from document from easy access -

```html
<template>
    <div class="slds-size_3-of-4">
        <div class="slds-box slds-box_x-small slds-text-align_center slds-m-around_x-small">Basic Carousel
            <lightning-carousel>
                <lightning-carousel-image
                    src="https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/assets/images/carousel/carousel-01.jpg"
                    header="First Card" description="First card description."
                    alternative-text="First card accessible description." href="javascript:void(0);">
                </lightning-carousel-image>
                <lightning-carousel-image
                    src="https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/assets/images/carousel/carousel-02.jpg"
                    header="Second Card" description="Second card description."
                    alternative-text="Second card accessible description." href="javascript:void(0);">
                </lightning-carousel-image>
                <lightning-carousel-image
                    src="https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/assets/images/carousel/carousel-03.jpg"
                    header="Third Card" description="Third card description."
                    alternative-text="Third card accessible description." href="javascript:void(0);">
                </lightning-carousel-image>
            </lightning-carousel>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```